# Elasticsearch Uneven Write Queue Distribution

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster with an even distribution of data that is routed based on the document `_id`- which is a random string. During normal operations, searching and writing to the cluster is done with an even distribution. However, when bulking updating documents in the cluster for several minutes, only 1-2 nodes appear to be working.

Here is what a bulk update operation looks like after several minutes of running-

```
  q  qs        node_id

  0 200 Wd5JFj4gRk-9pKL_Jubd3w
  0 200 FQ86BI1ASUS0tu-XQMuk6w
  0 200 dMeO029LSiqjwicm3YP8JA
  0 200 b8zAduWdRyO7P9Lz7hSFBQ
  0 200 K0o4v_mHRqSRNZWJpzvJPQ
224 200 HN1yQG_hRF2eiCyy_0Dpcg
  0 200 GXsc0FKsSUemue-e1Cuzsg
  0 200 LcDaZoipQA63UOg0_WHguA
  0 200 PdKFe7nLRaCnEqECNLpFvg
  0 200 glani3PYQ4qppwzvLQnjIQ
  0 200 T9jqycccQ-a03YtUCGVy0w
```

As you can see, the `HN1y` node becomes very active where the other nodes seem to go quiet. The total throughput of updates drops dramatically and the only way to resolve it is to pause the bulk update operaion, wait a minute, and resume. At which point we go through the same steps of even distribution to eventually one node appearing to do all of the work.

How can a cluster get into a situation like this? Does this suggest there really is an uneven distribution, or is something else going on?

Comment: Please post the result of `GET _nodes`. Feel free to remove any sensitive information (ip etc)

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris That output is too large for stackoverflow. Is there anything in particular you're looking for or another way for me to get you that information?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @AnirudhPanchangam I never figured this one out specifically. I ended up resharding the cluster and calling it a day.

Comment: @micah, I too was not able to figure out why this was occurring. However, i noticed that when we reduced the rate of requests being sent to logstash, it seemed to go down even out the write queue hold up. I have a feeling that this was induced by logstash not being able to properly distribute messages evenly. I also noticed that we had a perfect shard distribution, so all shard counts were evenly spread across the data nodes. However, i have nothing concrete to prove this.

Comment: @AnirudhPanchangam It would be odd but you could check if the shards on that node are larger than normal. Would be a sign of a hot partition.